# Why is multi Index outer Index Name right justified, as opposed to left

Tags: python, pandas

The below multi index data frame displays in jupyter lab with the outer indices 'O' and 'I' right justified. 
Whereas, in the 
cookbook https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/cookbook.html#cookbook-multi-index

..the outer indices appear left justified which makes more sense to me. 
Is there a setting I need to change to change the justification?
Do other people run the code and see a different justification than the cookbook?

```
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(x, y) for x in ['A', 'B', 'C'] for y in ['O', 'I']])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 6), index=['n', 'm'], columns=cols)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the same as in the cookbook. Not sure where the issue is

Comment: Wish I could screen shot it, but in my jupyter lab implementatin the outer layer of the multi index always shows up above the far RIGHT column of its sub index. Instead of the far LEFT column which makes more sense and shows up in the cook book.

Comment: I can confirm it isn't just you. I just used a MultiIndex in JupyterLab and see right justification, too. The cookbook is using IPython. If you use the classic notebook interface, you'll see left justification as well.  I prefer the left justification. Not sure why JupyterLab is going the other way, but in my case I can just switch views via `Help` > `Launch Classic Notebook` on the toolbar. I haven't tracked it well enough yet to find trick to fix Lab but [this](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2408) and [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/16080) look pertinent.